# Every irreducible $ G $ subrep is an irreducible $ H $ subrep implies every $ H $ subrep is a $ G $ subrep.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $ G $ be a completely reducible algebraic group (group for which every finite dimensional algebraic representation is completely reducible). Let $ H $ be an algebraic subgroup of $ G $ (then $ H $ must also be completely reducible).

Let $ V $ be a finite dimensional representation of $ G $. In general there may be $ H $ subreps of $ V $ which are not $ G $ subreps. For example take $ G=GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $, $ V=\mathbb{C}^2 $ the natural representation and $ H $ trivial. Then any 1d subspace is an $ H $ subrep but not a $ G $ subrep.

However, what is we furthermore suppose that every irreducible $ G $ subrep of $ V $ is also irreducible as an $ H $ subrep of $ V $. Does that imply that every $ H $ subrep of $ V $ is also a $ G $ subrep of $ V $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For a simple example, let $G$ be any group with a nontrivial $1$-dimensional representation and $H$ be trivial.  If you take a direct sum $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ of two non-isomorphic $1$-dimensional representations of $G$, then each irreducible subrepresentation of $V$ is still irreducible over $H$.  However, there are subrepresentations over $H$ that are not subrepresentations over $G$ (take any $1$-dimensional subspace of $V$ different from $V_1$ and $V_2$).

Comment: Do you know any counterexamples where $ G $ is a semisimple Lie group? Or is it better to ask that as a separate question

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: I've asked a new question with the hypothesis "every irreducible $G$
 subrep is an irreducible $H$ subrep and distinct irreps of $G$ correspond to distinct irreps of $H$." Distinct irreps of $ G $ not branching to distinct irreps of $ H $ is essentially what happens in your counterexample. With this improved hypothesis I ask for the same conclusion, that: "every $H$ subrep of $V$ is also a $G$ subrep of $V$." https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4669443/758507 Thanks for helping me improve my question!